StatsForecast AutoARIMA taking too long to fit
I'm experiencing a rather “strange” issue with Nixtla's StatsForecast that's severely blocking my progress. I'm explaining it here to see if anyone has any ideas to try, or if those of you who have it installed can test if it works for you.
The case is that until yesterday it was running reasonably fast, and today suddenly it's about 100 times slower, no exaggeration.
The documentation mentions fitting 10 models on 1 million series in under 5 minutes... Well, I run this code and my computer can't finish (over 30 minutes and still running):
import random 
import pandas as pd
from statsforecast import StatsForecast
from statsforecast.models import AutoARIMA
import time


random.seed(1)
points = 500
test_data = pd.DataFrame({
    "ds": pd.date_range(start="2024-06-01", periods=points, freq="W"),
    "unique_id": "test",
    "y": random.choices(range(0, 100), k=points)
})
model = StatsForecast(
    models=[AutoARIMA(season_length=52)],
    freq="W",
    n_jobs=-1,
)
start = time.time()
results = model.forecast(df=test_data, h=6)
print(time.time() - start)
results= model.forecast(df=test_data, h=6)
results

Tests I've done (none worked):

Restart the computer.
Create a new Python 3.10 environment from scratch and run it via terminal without PyCharm or anything.
Play with the number of cores, it doesn't seem to affect and it never uses more than 100% CPU.
Test on other machines: It seems to run much faster and with the same version of statsforecast 1.7.5.

May be some of my PC configuration? I'm running on Ubuntu 20.04, 16 GiB RAM and an Intel Core i7 1.8Ghz x 8.
Any ideas?
EDIT: Fixed the seed and added time counting.

I'm getting the same problem
